# Entity Framework Core : “Invalid attempt to call ReadAsync when reader is closed”

Tags: entity-framework, triggers, entity-framework-core

I am new in Entity framework core, I am making a simple short project. In my project I use trigger. But when deleting **multiple items**, the trigger shows an error :
"Invalid attempt to call ReadAsync when reader is closed”.

I googled a lot but was unable to find any solution in this situation.
How can I solve this problem?

Below is my code :

```
 Triggers<Items>.Deleted += async e => {
       decimal convertedQuantity = e.Entity.MeasurementUnitSetup.ConversionRatio * e.Entity.IssuedQuantity;
       var warehouseItem = e.Context.Entry(e.Entity.Warehouse).Collection(o => o.WarehouseItems)
                      .Query()
                      .SingleOrDefault(wi => wi.WarehouseId == e.Entity.WarehouseId && wi.MeasurementUnitSetup.ItemId == e.Entity.MeasurementUnitSetup.ItemId);

    if (warehouseItem.Quantity - convertedQuantity >= 0)
          warehouseItem.Quantity -= convertedQuantity;

    await e.Context.SaveChangesAsync(); //From here error showing
   }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using MultipleActiveResultSets=True in your connection string ?

Comment: I haven't used the Triggers package, but I'm guessing you get multiple, concurrent executions of the trigger action when deleting multiple Items.  A DbContext cannot be accessed by concurrent threads, so you'll need to serialize the calls, or figure out how to have the triggers fire async, but one-at-a-time.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue because I was returning "void" in my function mistakenly:-

> **public async Void OnGet()**

Then I replaced "void" with "Task"

> **public async Task OnGet()**

Answer (score 2):

When I came across this error it was because I was calling the DbContext actions outside the main thread which had closed and started to tidy / dispose of the necessary resources. To resolve this you will need to keep the main thread open by awaiting each database call on the main thread or by creating a new scope which can instantiate a new DbContext and keep it in scope until your action has finished.

```
using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<YourDbContext>();
```

Answer (score 0):

For those, who also in search for the answer: in my case it was

```
_refreshTokenRepository.Update(updatedRefreshToken);
await _refreshTokenRepository.SaveAsync(); //this part was absent and caused the same error
```

I hope, it can help someone